# Setting multiple set-cookie headers in Dart with Shelf

Tags: http, cookies, dart, dart-shelf

I need to set multiple 'set-cookie' headers in Shelf, but since headers is a `Map<String,String>`, setting the second one replaces the first and so on because keys are unique. How can I solve this in Dart?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open feature request https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18844 and also https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18845
Here is an implementation https://github.com/wstrange/shelf_simple_session/blob/master/lib/src/cookie.dart